# Linking external libraries in PPAPI plugin

Tags: google-nativeclient, ppapi

First of all am new to PPAPI plugin development. Earlier i have been using NPAPI plugin to perform certain functionality which in turn uses windows APIs.Now since NPAPI is obsolete, i am trying PPAPI. My question is can i link windows APIs to PPAPI? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Bennet mentioned, it is not possible to make calls to the Windows API. If this is necessary for your application, try making a Chrome Extension and using [Native Messaging](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html#native-messaging) instead.

From the link:

> Extensions can exchange messages with native applications. Native
>   applications that  support this feature must register a native
>   messaging host that knows how to communicate with the extension.
>   Chrome starts the host in a separate process and communicates with it 
>   using standard input and standard output streams.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to call Windows functions.  If it were, then it would be trivial to escape the NaCl security sandbox.

Comment: Not even DLL calls are permitted ?

Comment: If you could call anything that was in a DLL, then it wouldn't be much of a sandbox. PPAPI is not just NPAPI with a different name; by design, you can't make arbitrary calls from it.